# Change the color of a portion of a gridview templatefield

Tags: asp.net, gridview, colors

I have a templatefield in a gridview to display contact details. I managed to format the static parts, i.e. 'Contact', 'Position', 'Number' and 'Mobile'.

**Contact:** Dieter
**Position:** Code-jockey
**Number:** 061 323 9484
**Mobile:** 027 450 2345

My code is as follows:
   `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Details">`
   `<ItemTemplate>`
    `<asp:Label ID="txtContactDetails" runat="server" CssClass="right" TextMode="MultiLine" HtmlEncode="false"`
    `Text='<%# String.Format("<b>Contact:   </b>{0}", Eval("ContactName")) +`
    `If(Eval("ContactPosition").ToString = "", "", String.Format("</br><b>Position:  </b>{0}", Eval("ContactPosition"))) +`
    `String.Format("</br><b>Number:   </b>{0}", Eval("ContactNumber")) +`
    `If(Eval("MobileNumber").ToString = "", "", String.Format("</br><b>Mobile:  </b>{0}", Eval("MobileNumber")))%>'`
    `ToolTip='<%# Bind("ContactName")%>'`
    `BorderStyle="None" Width="100%" />`
    `</ItemTemplate>`
    `<ItemStyle CssClass="right" />`
    `</asp:TemplateField>`

I don't know whether this can be done, but I would like to change the color of the Number (i.e. only the **Eval("ContactNumber")**) to e.g. orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `OnRowDataBound` event is the perfect event to customize any row of a Gridview based on its data values, your requirement can be accomplished a bit differently from within the Markup Code only .

```
Text='<%# String.Format(@"</br><b>Number: </b>
<span class=""contactNumber"">{0}</span>", Eval("ContactNumber"))%>'
```

Note the use of @ as:`String.Format(@"` , and double quotes "" 2 times around class attribute as:

```
<span class=""contactNumber"">
```

Now, either in your CSS file or inline in your markup file, just specify the color you want to use and that will get applied to ContactNumber only.

Inline CSS example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .contactNumber {

    color: orange;

  }
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks FlopScientist. I couldn't figure out where in the CSS I need to put the code, but using your logic I changed it to:  `String.Format("</br><b>Number:   </b><span style=color:orangered>{0}</span>", Eval("ContactNumber"))`  Works great! (cannot vote, I don't have enough reputation. Sorry)

Comment: Good to know this solution helped you. you can accept this as an answer if the idea presented  helped you here!!